# BloomFilter Library implementation with byte[] -> BitArray translation

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

I have implemented a bloom filter library that internally uses BitArray. The filter is simple, it has two methods: Add and Contains. The created BitArray filter is then translated to a byte[], which is then serialized and exchanged by internal services.

A few constrains:

1. The BloomFilter is exchanged between multiple services using internal API platform and with how the platform is designed (to avoid race conditions), we cannot directly add items to input BloomFilter and must instead copy the filter each time before any updates.
2. We convert it into byte[] for two reasons, the data exchange does not allow BitArray due to platform restricts again
3. For the filter itself, we would like to use every Bit of the byte [] since we just check for 0s/1s. For this very reason, we uuse BitArray inside BloomFilter library and the library provides necessary translations between byte -> bits and vice versa.

Below is the code for the library:

```
public class BloomFilter<T>
    {
        public BitArray? Filter { get; private set; }
        public BloomFilter(byte[] bytes)
        {
            this.Filter = new BitArray(bytes);
        }

        public BloomFilter(int size)
        {
            this.Filter = new BitArray(size);
        }

        // convert Byte Array to Xap Blob
        public byte[] ConvertFilterToBlob(BitArray Filter)
        {
            return BitArrayUtils.BitArrayToByteArray(Filter);
        }

        // Add items to filter
        public void Add(T item)
        {
            if ((this.Filter?.Length ?? 0) > 0 && item != null)
            {
                foreach (int hashValue in GetHashValues(item))
                {
                    this.Filter[hashValue % this.Filter.Length] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        // Check if filter contains item
        public bool Contains(T item)
        {
            if ((this.Filter?.Length ?? 0) <= 0 || item == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            foreach (int hashValue in GetHashValues(item))
            {
                if (this.Filter[hashValue % this.Filter.Length])
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        // Get list of hash values
        private IEnumerable<int> GetHashValues(T item)
        {
                int hashValue = ComputeHash(item.GetHashCode() ^ i);
                yield return hashValue;
        }

        // Compute Hash for bloom filter
        private int ComputeHash(int value)
        {
            using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
            {
                byte[] data = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
                byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(data);
                return Math.Abs(BitConverter.ToInt32(hash, 0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code for byte[] -> BitArray translation

```
public static class BitArrayUtils
    {
        public static byte[] BitArrayToByteArray(BitArray bits)
        {
            if (bits == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int numBytes = (bits.Length + 7) / 8;
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[numBytes];
            int bitIndex = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < numBytes; i++)
            {
                int bitValue = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                {
                    if (bitIndex < bits.Length && bits[bitIndex])
                        bitValue |= (1 << j);
                    bitIndex++;
                }
                byteArray[i] = (byte)bitValue;
            }

            return byteArray;
        }

        public static BitArray ByteArrayToBitArray(byte[] bytes)
        { 
            return new BitArray(bytes); 
        }

    }
```

The code works correctly for most cases and have tested it, except for one case. When the initial size of the BloomFilter is not a multiple of 8. The below unit test covers this case.

```
[Fact]
 public void AddItems_ContainsTrue()
        {
            this.filter = new BloomFilter<string>(300);
            foreach (var item in dataList)
            {
                this.filter.Add(item);
            }

            Assert.True(this.filter.Contains("id1"));
            Assert.True(this.filter.Contains("id2"));
            Assert.True(this.filter.Filter.Count == 300);

            byte[] copyData = this.filter.ConvertFilterToBlob(this.filter.Filter);
            Assert.Equal(Math.Ceiling((float)this.filter.Filter.Count / 8), copyData.Length);

            BloomFilter<string> filterNew = new BloomFilter<string>(copyData);
            byte[] copyData2 = this.filter.ConvertFilterToBlob(filterNew.Filter);
            Assert.True(filterNew.Filter.Count == 300); // This is false, new count is 304
            Assert.True(filterNew.Contains("id1")); // This is false
        }
```

When the initial size of the BloomFilter is 300, when converting to bytes, we essentially write divide the bit length by 8 and round up the result to get the size.
Problem with this approach is that next time when translate the byte[] to BitArray to update the filter, the BitArray since is more because we rounded up. Now, when we check if an item already exists in the filter, since the result of index = (hash % size) is different, the assertion fails although the item still exists in the original index.

The easiest way to fix this is to make sure the size of the filter is always a multiple of 8. But this is not always a guarantee if anyone else were to use this library. Is there a way to point convert the hash to an index value without using the size of BitArray? or any alternative ideas to make the code easier to use with for people who do not know how the library works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two easy solutions:

1. Keep a `Size`, which is the size the user requested, but also keep an `allocatedSize`, which is `Size` rounded up to the next multiple of 8 bits. Do all of your hash calculations with the `allocatedSize` value.
2. Document the constructor to say that if the requested size is not divisible by 8, the next higher multiple of 8 will be used. So if the constructor is called with `var f = new BloomFilter<foo>(7)`, the filter will be constructed to hold 8 values.

I can't see any particular disadvantages to either of those solutions. I prefer the second one because you handle the problem in the constructor and never have to think about it again.